# Get mouse position relative to a zoomed out div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent

What I'm looking to accomplish is to get the position of the mouse in relation to a zoomed out div with matrix transform. As you will see in the fiddle below I have a red div with a width of `4000px`, but since it's zoomed out it appears smaller then said `4000px`. What should happen is if you click on the intersecting lines in the red div, `relX` should read (around) `2000` and `relY` should read around `325`.

```
$(".crazyWide").click(function(e){
    var clickPos = $(this).offset(); 
    var relX = e.pageX - clickPos.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - clickPos.top;

    //Used to display current click coords
    $(".debug").empty();
    $(".debug").prepend("relX: " + relX + " relY: " + relY);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdbxvh13/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is shrunk to a factor of `0.12` in both directions. As such, you can calculate the relative mouse click position by dividing the `relX` and `relY` by `0.12`:

```
$(".debug").prepend("relX: " + (relX / 0.12) + " relY: " + (relY / 0.12));
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdbxvh13/1/)

Comment: FGITW  beat me to it :)

Comment: I feel like an idiot now not realizing that, thanks for the help Rory