# How to factor in zoom(i.e scale) when html element need to follow mouse. i.e sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve issue where html element needs to follow mouse. It works as expected when I have `scale(1)` but once I increase or decrease scale, I cannot find way to factor in scale.

```js
const nestedBox1 = document.getElementById("nestedBox1")
const box1 = document.getElementById('box1')

const scale = 1

box1.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    nestedBox1.style.transform = `translate(${(e.clientX)}px, ${e.clientY}px)`
})
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
}

#nestedBox1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <div id="nestedBox1">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the correct mouse position in relation to a div that has has a scale transform applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467122/how-to-get-the-correct-mouse-position-in-relation-to-a-div-that-has-has-a-scale)

Comment: @0stone0 Your comment lead me to another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260700/get-mouse-position-relative-to-a-zoomed-out-div?rq=3. That answered my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to problem was since we scaled(i.e zoom) div, we need to remove that scale(i.e zoom) by dividing.

This question helped [Get mouse position relative to a zoomed out div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260700/get-mouse-position-relative-to-a-zoomed-out-div?rq=3) me figure our solution.

```js
const nestedBox1 = document.getElementById("nestedBox1")
const box1 = document.getElementById('box1')

const scale = 0.75

box1.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    nestedBox1.style.transform = `translate(${(e.clientX - 60)/scale}px, ${(e.clientY - 60)/scale}px)`
})
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.75);
}

#nestedBox1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <div id="nestedBox1">
  
  </div>
</div>
```